# android.os.CancellationSignal.isCanceled() return false after calling android.os.CancellationSignal.cancel()

Tags: android, junit, kotlin

Why does `isCanceled()` return false after I call the `cancel()` function? In the source code I see what `mIsCanceled` variable must be set to true then I call `cancel()` function. Use this test to reproduce the error:

```
package some.package.com

import android.os.CancellationSignal
import junit.framework.TestCase.assertTrue
import org.junit.Test

class TestCancelationSignal {

    @Test
    fun SaveToFileEncryptData() {
        val cancelationSignal = CancellationSignal()
        cancelationSignal.cancel()
        assertTrue(cancelationSignal.isCanceled)
    }

}
```

Comment: can you add your function code too ?

Comment: @Redman Unfortunately no. But what's the difference. The question is why exactly such a case does not work.